# Javascript for draggable, zoomable map with Google-Maps-like features

Tags: javascript, map

I'm looking for a JavaScript-based tool for displaying draggable, zoomable maps. It has to have the following features:

- Can add markers, labels, balloons (a la Google maps)
- Must be scriptable after creation (so I can add or update content on the fly)
- must work offline
- must scale to the browser size (specifically, it must be mobile friendly)

Ideally, pure JavaScript or based on the jQuery framework. I'd rather not have to have competing frameworks on a single page.

Comment: Must work offline... this means you want to add the maps as images and you are looking for a script just to pan and zoom?

Comment: Right, but also things like markers and popups.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) does what I want. I'll update this answer if I run into problems with it.